# Docker, Dockerfile and using wait-for-it before I start my next service

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, keycloak

I have 2 Dockerfiles , 'app'  relies on the 'sso'.

a) keycloak-Dockerfile: `FROM jboss/keycloak-mysql:3.3.0.Final`

This service is called 'sso' in my docker-compose.yml-file

b) my wildfly service Dockerfile : `FROM openjdk:8u111-jdk-alpine` where I deploy my java-service

This service is called 'app' in my docker-compose.yml-file

So the keycloak, the 'sso'-service, takes a while to deploy. I want my 'app' to deploy after the 'sso'-service has started.
One thing to have in mind about my configuration is that the 'sso'  starts up port 8080 pretty fast but takes time to get all the keycloak-realms in place.

This was my first approach in my 'app'-Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8u111-jdk-alpine

RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache tini openssl bash

COPY target/accounts-api-swarm.jar /usr/src/myapp/
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp

RUN wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/master/wait-for-it.sh -O /wait-for-it.sh && chmod +x /wait-for-it.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/tini", "--", "/wait-for-it.sh", "sso:8080", "-t", "360", "--"]
CMD java -jar accounts-api-swarm.jar -Sinitdata
```

That approach does not work, because accounts-api-swarm.jar is deployed before all the keycloak realms are in place ..... (starts just after sso:8080 is up)

My next attempt was to (how_I_believe_wait-for-it.sh_works) is to see if the 'master' realm is up and available.

```
FROM openjdk:8u111-jdk-alpine

RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache tini openssl bash

COPY target/accounts-api-swarm.jar /usr/src/myapp/
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp

RUN wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/master/wait-for-it.sh \
    -O /wait-for-it.sh \
    && chmod +x /wait-for-it.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/tini", "--", "/wait-for-it.sh", "sso:8080/auth/realms/master/", "-t", "360", "--"]
CMD java -jar accounts-api-swarm.jar -Sinitdata
```

That does not work.

The application works if I do things manually, I start up keycloak ('sso') waits until it is deployed and then I start up 'app' - but I do not seem to be able to make this work ....

I have also tried the following syntax ... tried using `--strict` as well

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/tini", "--"]
CMD  /wait-for-it.sh sso:8080/auth/realms/master/ -t 360 -- java -jar accounts-api-swarm.jar -Sinitdata
```

I hope that you can give me a hand here.

regards, i

Answer (score 3):

You can use a container called [dadarek/wait-for-dependencies](https://github.com/dadarek/docker-wait-for-dependencies) as a mechanism to wait for services to be up. Handling this type of thing at runtime should be easier than trying to handle at build time.

You didn't post your `docker-compose.yml` file, but here is how you can implement it.

1). Add a new service to your docker-compose.yml

```
  waitforsso:
    image: dadarek/wait-for-dependencies
    depends_on:
      - sso 
    command: sso:8080
```

Your docker-compose.yml should look now look like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  waitforsso:
    image: dadarek/wait-for-dependencies
  depends_on:
    - sso 
  command: sso:8080

  # MySQL database for Keycloak
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    env_file: ./env/.envmysql
    volumes:
      - db_accounts:/var/lib/mysql

  # Keycloak server
  sso:
    image: dina/keycloak:v0.1
    env_file: 
      - ./env/.envmysql
      - ./env/.envaccounts
    environment:
      - TZ=Europe/Stockholm
      - MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR=mysql
      - MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT=3306
      - PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true 
    links:
      - db:mysql

  # Java JSON-API
  api:
    image: dina/accounts-api:v0.1
    env_file:  
      - ./env/.envaccounts
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=alpha-api.dina-web.net
    volumes:
      - ./env/.envapi:/usr/src/myapp/project-initdata.yml
    ports:
      - "8181:8181"

  # Keycloak API proxy
  ws:
    image: nginx
    container_name: alpha-sso.dina-web.net
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=alpha-sso.dina-web.net
  #  links:
  #    - api 
    volumes:
      - ./nginx-conf/app.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/app.conf
      - ./nginx-certs:/etc/nginx/ssl
    depends_on:
      - waitforsso
      - db

  # Ember frontend
  ui:
    image: dina/accounts-ui:v0.1
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.template
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=alpha-accounts.dina-web.net
      - VIRTUAL_PROTO=http
      - NGINX_HOST=alpha-accounts.dina-web.net
      - NGINX_PORT=80
    command: /bin/ash -c "envsubst '$$NGINX_HOST $$NGINX_PORT $$NGINX_ROOT $$NGINX_INDEX' < /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"

  # Generic proxy
  proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy:alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - ./certs:/etc/nginx/certs

volumes:
  db_accounts:
```

3). You must remove anything related to `wait-for-it.sh` from your relevant Dockerfiles, then rebuild those images.

4). Startup compose

```
docker-compose run --rm waitforsso
docker-compose up -d sso db api ws proxy ui
```

The result is that your `ws` service should now wait for port 8080 to be up(i.e. your `sso` service to be up)

Comment: Thank you for your effort grizzhedj! I am not able to get this to work. If you want to have a go then here is the repo ( https://github.com/DINA-Web/accounts-docker/tree/development-alpha-20171101 ) - the Makefile has all the recipes, 'make all' starts all the containers ... run 'make initialize-mail' once before you start up. I have been looking at the wait-for-it.sh-script wanting to enhance it, so that it would wait for a service that is deployed ( see https://github.com/DINA-Web/accounts-docker/issues/17 ) - regards, i

Comment: Thanks for posting the repo - that helps. You will need to remove the `wait-for-it.sh` lines from your Dockerfiles, and rebuild those images. I have updated my answer with more specifics